# Как создать API на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Как создать API на сайте, написанном на laravel 5.6? В документации на русском только описана API-аутентификация.
Дайте, пожалуйста, подробный ответ: что в роутере, контроллере и т.д.?

Comment: Немного вопрос не понял. https://laravel.com/api/5.6/ - так вот по моему api

Comment: Если не поняли вопрос, не стоит давать ответ) Автор хочет свое внешнее апи разработать, и спрашивает как это грамотно сделать -.-

Comment: та я думаю что вас никто не будет ограничивать, делайте как знаете, практикуйтесь. в роутере инструкции по роуту, а в контроллере логика (ваш Кеп).

Comment: Прежде чем делать, почитай доки и посмотри видео. API роуты имеют одноименный префикс и имеют посредников, отличных от веб роутов. Если нужна аутентификация запросов, то попробуй использовать `jwt`. На ютубе есть ролики, в packagist'е есть хорошие библиотеки для работы с jwt. Не нравятся jwt? - генерируй сам токены и держи их в базе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте стандартный Laravel проект и посмотрите как там устроено в роутинге и конфиге для работы API. Аутентификация посредством паспорта не обязательна, можно использовать уже имеющееся.

В основном это сводится к созданию файла api.php в /routes, прописывание для его использования в RouteServiceProvider:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

и в app/Http/Kernel.php для посредников:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
'web' => [// Фильтры здесь ],
'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        'jsonable'
    ]];
```

Для аутентификации можно использовать посредник, я к примеру использую Sentinel и проверяю пользователя по X-API-KEY в заголовке запроса:

```
class SentinelAuth 
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $apiKey = $request->header('X-API-KEY');
    if (!isset($apiKey)) {
        return response('Unauthorized', 401);
    }

    if (!$user = Sentinel::findByPersistenceCode($apiKey)) {
        return response('Unauthorized', 401);
    } else {
        Sentinel::setUser($user);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

И он используется в роутинге таким образом:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['sentinel-auth']], function () {
    Route::post('/MY_FUNCTION', 'MyController@myFunction')->name('myFunction');
});
```

Главное и его не забыть зарегистрировать как посредник. ;)